# How to fix "Failed to obtain JDBC Connection" datasource error in my java application

Tags: mysql, spring, jdbc, datasource, mysql-connector

I have a little training project running under Java Spring MVC and using MySQL on WAMP Server), it was working but i cloned it and had to reinstall database (restored from a dump) and Wamp64 also, but now my java application cannot connect and i get different errors.

In IntelliJ IDEA when i test the connection to the database, the connection is successfull, even in phpmyadmin, but not when i launch my application.

`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library?serverTimezone=UTC`  (i had to use server timezone to fixe timezone error)

It's looking like my java app doesn't use the good datasource configuration, and instead use the old one but i can't figure out why.

My application is using SOAP protocol to connect to my webservices.

The main error is a javaNullPointer exception on the line where i try to get the user from database trough an input form.

The other error is (when i go in debug mode):

> Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: AccÃ¨s refusÃ© pour l'utilisateur: 'root'@'@localhost' (mot de passe: OUI) error.

This project was cloned from an old project. I suppose there is somewhere an old datasource used by the application.

It looks like my application uses old login settings for mysql (login: root, password: password). I recently changed the login information to my database, to an "admin_library" login that has all the privileges and a password.

I invalidated and restarted the IntelliJ cache, made an "mvn clean install", but when I run my two tomcat servers (one for the webservice, another one for the soap webserviceclient), my login screen appears but I have a null point exception (apparently due to a database connection problem.

Here is my configuration:

**pom.xml:**

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.15</version>
            </dependency>
```

**WEB-INF/SpringMVCDispatcher-servlet.xml:**

```
<!-- CONFIG JDBC DATASOURCE // -->
    <bean id = "jdbcTemplate"
          class = "org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name = "dataSource" ref = "dataSource" />
    </bean>
    <bean id = "dataSource"
          class = "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name = "driverClassName" value = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name = "url" value = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library"/>
        <property name = "username" value = "admin_library"/>
        <property name = "password" value = "password"/>
    </bean>
```

```
Type Rapport d'exception

message Request processing failed; nested exception is com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: AccÃ¨s refusÃ© pour l'utilisateur: 'root'@'@localhost' (mot de passe: OUI) Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.

description Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne qui l'a empêché de satisfaire la requête.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: AccÃ¨s refusÃ© pour l'utilisateur: 'root'@'@localhost' (mot de passe: OUI) Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:901)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
cause mère

com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: AccÃ¨s refusÃ© pour l'utilisateur: 'root'@'@localhost' (mot de passe: OUI) Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.
    com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:193)
    com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:128)
    com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:253)
    com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:206)
    com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:293)
    com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:119)
    com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:92)
    com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:161)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.findByEmail(Unknown Source)
    fr.projet3.library.controller.LoginController.postLogin(LoginController.java:57)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:142)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:901)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
note La trace complète de la cause mère de cette erreur est disponible dans les fichiers journaux de ce serveur.
```

A look into the controller:

```java
@PostMapping(value = {"/login","/", ""})
    public String postLogin(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userLoginForm")UserLoginForm userLoginForm, BindingResult bindingResult, ModelMap modelMap, HttpSession session){
        if(!bindingResult.hasErrors()){

            UserWS u = libraryWS.findByEmail(userLoginForm.getEmail());
            if(u == null){
                return "login";
            }
            session.setAttribute("currentUser", u);

            return "redirect:/userloan";
        }
        return "login";
    }
```

Comment: The error suggests you are attempting to connect with a user `'root'@'@localhost', which doesn't match the credentials in your XML. Use the stacktrace to find where the error occurs and trace how it gets its credentials.

Comment: Judging by the stacktrace, you might be looking in the wrong application for the error. You are getting a `ServerSOAPFaultException`, which means that you are communicating with another application using SOAP, and that application is throwing the error.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel is right the problem is comming from the application   
 libraryWS  when you try to retrieve the user in your controller, you need to change the username and password also in this application. com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.findByEmail(Unknown Source)

Comment: Thanks @all, i found that i have forgotten to edit an "applicationContext.xml" file  also for the libraryWS. Now i got a timezone error: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Paris, Madrid (heure dété)' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

Comment: Okay, i fixed this error also using: ?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&serverTimezone=UTC   to my datasource connexion   EG: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&amp;serverTimezone=UTC"   I will look deeper later if i can fix it with a "cleaner" solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had to edit an "applicationContext.xml" file also for the libraryWS. Then i got a timezone error:
*`Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Paris, Madrid (heure dété)' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.`*

i fixed this error also using:

`?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&serverTimezone=UTC` to my datasource connexion EG: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&amp;serverTimezone=UTC`"