# MockMvc-based tests fail after upgrading of spring-security and spring-boot libs

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, mockmvc

I upgraded spring-security dependencies from 5.2.10.RELEASE to 5.6.0, and spring-boot from 2.1.18.RELEASE to 2.4.11. After this upgrade, all the our controller tests that use MockMvc fail with stack trace below.
Any help is appreciated.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to unwrap proxied object

```
at org.springframework.test.util.AopTestUtils.getUltimateTargetObject(AopTestUtils.java:97)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.SpringBootMockResolver.resolve(SpringBootMockResolver.java:35)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.resolve(MockUtil.java:118)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.isMock(MockUtil.java:108)
at org.mockito.internal.util.DefaultMockingDetails.isMock(DefaultMockingDetails.java:32)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockReset.get(MockReset.java:106)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:82)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:70)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:57)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:293)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.BatchConfigurationException: org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection: DataSource returned null from getConnection(): javax.sql.DataSource#0 bean
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.DefaultBatchConfigurer.initialize(DefaultBatchConfigurer.java:119)
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.AbstractBatchConfiguration.getConfigurer(AbstractBatchConfiguration.java:118)
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration.initialize(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:115)
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$ReferenceTargetSource.createObject(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:143)
at org.springframework.aop.target.AbstractLazyCreationTargetSource.getTarget(AbstractLazyCreationTargetSource.java:88)
at org.springframework.test.util.AopTestUtils.getUltimateTargetObject(AopTestUtils.java:90)
... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection: DataSource returned null from getConnection(): javax.sql.DataSource#0 bean
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:363)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:395)
at org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType.fromMetaData(DatabaseType.java:102)
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:183)
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.DefaultBatchConfigurer.createJobRepository(DefaultBatchConfigurer.java:134)
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.DefaultBatchConfigurer.initialize(DefaultBatchConfigurer.java:113)
... 35 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection: DataSource returned null from getConnection(): javax.sql.DataSource#0 bean
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:85)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:337)
... 40 more

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to unwrap proxied object

```
at org.springframework.test.util.AopTestUtils.getUltimateTargetObject(AopTestUtils.java:97)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.SpringBootMockResolver.resolve(SpringBootMockResolver.java:35)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.resolve(MockUtil.java:118)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.isMock(MockUtil.java:108)
at org.mockito.internal.util.DefaultMockingDetails.isMock(DefaultMockingDetails.java:32)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockReset.get(MockReset.java:106)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:82)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:70)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:64)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:445)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:94)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.BatchConfigurationException: org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection: DataSource returned null from getConnection(): javax.sql.DataSource#0 bean
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.DefaultBatchConfigurer.initialize(DefaultBatchConfigurer.java:119)
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.AbstractBatchConfiguration.getConfigurer(AbstractBatchConfiguration.java:118)
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration.initialize(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:115)
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$ReferenceTargetSource.createObject(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:143)
at org.springframework.aop.target.AbstractLazyCreationTargetSource.getTarget(AbstractLazyCreationTargetSource.java:88)
at org.springframework.test.util.AopTestUtils.getUltimateTargetObject(AopTestUtils.java:90)
... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection: DataSource returned null from getConnection(): javax.sql.DataSource#0 bean
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:363)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:395)
at org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType.fromMetaData(DatabaseType.java:102)
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:183)
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.DefaultBatchConfigurer.createJobRepository(DefaultBatchConfigurer.java:134)
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.DefaultBatchConfigurer.initialize(DefaultBatchConfigurer.java:113)
... 34 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection: DataSource returned null from getConnection(): javax.sql.DataSource#0 bean
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:85)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:337)
... 39 more

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

You are not seeing the whole stacktrace and the root cause so basically you don't have yet the real cause.

This is usually a problem with the connection string, for example you are missing something about the time-zone or not allowing key retrieval... check these other answers:

- [How to fix "Failed to obtain JDBC Connection" datasource error in my java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57906700/how-to-fix-failed-to-obtain-jdbc-connection-datasource-error-in-my-java-applic)
- [Connection Java - MySQL : Public Key Retrieval is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50379839/connection-java-mysql-public-key-retrieval-is-not-allowed/51132931)

Comment: Thanks Raul, in debugging I see that the failure happens when SpringBootMockResolver.resolve method is called for object: JdkDynamicAopProxy.
Does it help to direct to what configuration is missing?